# Our Own Coin And Gnosis-Safe

Tags: tokens, gnosis-safe

I and a friend are creating a website that will use our own erc20 token and will be used on the site to pay users for joining, NFTs, donations, memberships and use of the site

my question is if we were to add the wallet in which this coin is in will we need to verify it transactions that come out of it every time

Answer (score 1):

Every action that a Safe should perform needs to be confirmed by the owners (the threshold has to be met). An overview of the Safe functionality can be found in the [Safe docs](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/introduction/the-programmable-account/gnosis-safe).

For automation it is possible to use [modules](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/modules-1), which have different access logic.

Examples for such modules can be found in the [safe-modules repository](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-modules).